# Directly manipulating a DataSet

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have a *lightweight* data-basey kind of thing. Functionally, I'd like to read and write tables out to disk(plus maybe some other info in the future).

I chose to use the DataSet object, paired with the DataGridView control for the IO. The DataSet object can serialize out to disk and back again via the handle XML read/write functions.

However, there does not seem to be an *obvious* way to add information to the DataView control and have the DataSet object updated. Among other things, the DataGridView won't add a row for me in run-time and won't let me programmatically run the addrow method.

Clearly, I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

---

This has been suggested:

`dataSet1.Tables["mytable"].Rows.Add();`

But System.Data.DataRow does not permit direct construction, and I want to add a blank row for the DataGridView to fill in?

edit2: I'm dumb. There's a new row function.

Hmm. I'm wondering if this is just a Wrong Approach.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your edit

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the content of the `DataGridView` programmatically, modify the `DataSet` itself instead. It will automatically update the `DataGridView` if it is databound to the `DataSet` (using the `DataSource` and `DataMember` properties). Changes made by the user in the `DataGridView` will be automatically reflected in the `DataSet`.

---

UPDATE

> ```
> dataSet1.Tables["mytable"].Rows.Add();
> ```
>
> But System.Data.DataRow does not permit direct construction, and I want to add a blank row for the DataGridView to fill in?

You can construct a `DataRow` manually :

```
DataRow row = dataSet1.Tables["mytable"].NewRow();
row["column1"] = value1;
row["column2"] = value2;
...
dataSet1.Tables["mytable"].Rows.Add(row);
```

If you just want a blank row, just don't initialize the fields...

If you have a `BindingSource` between the `DataSet` and the `DataGridView`, call `AddNew` on the `BindingSource`. It will add a blank line. You can also use a `BindingNavigator` control, which handles the calls to the `BindingSource` methods.

Comment: Umph. I'll putz with this later. It's not writing in/out correctly. In another note, Architecture Astronaut detected in MS system design. >.<